# How does this MOSFET with the configuration of its gate work?

Tags: capacitor, mosfet, dc-dc-converter

I'm seeing the schematic of a Notebook HP Pavilion dv9000 ([download](http://www.s-manuals.com/pdf/motherboard/quanta/quanta_at8_r1a_schematics.pdf)). On page 33 you can see this part:

[image: image1]

Take a look at the configuration of PQ37. I mean its gate. the gate is connected to PC170 and PC117 and PD15 and PD21. why? what and how does this configuration do/work?

Comment: It looks like a voltage multiplier. The DL5 pin is switched between +5 and GND to dive the PQ37 as is a synchronous rectifier. And at the same time, this voltage is used in voltage multiplier. PC170 is changed to 5V and when DL5 at +5V the PC170 charged the PC169 capacitor to 10V. And this 10V is used to charge PC117 and PC117 charge is used to charged the PC118 capacitor to +15V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FET is part of a synchronous buck converter.  The gate driver is also used to drive 2 charge pumps.

For example, PC170 is charged to 5V minus a diode drop when the FET gate goes low, then pumps that charge onto PC169 when the gate goes high.

This creates a roughly 10V supply for use elsewhere.

The FET gates are drawn differently from the usual convention where the right angle is on the source side, but they are N-FETs.